# Crear servidor web en casa y visualizarlo desde otra red diferente a la mia (hacer el server publico)

Tags: linux, webservice, web, servidor, ip

quisiera saber como hago para que la web que tengo montada en un servidor apache de forma local se pueda ver en otros computadores que no estén en mi red de internet, ya abri el puerto 80 y configure la ip con DMZ pero no logro hacer que solo con poner mi ip publica se abra la web que tengo, en conclusión quiero que al ingresar desde otra red con mi ip publica se visualice la web.
(No quiero hacer uso de herramientas como no-ip etc)
por cierto uso debian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo hice algo parecido en mi casa.

Una vez montado el server en casa, y ya podía verlo desde mi ordenador con la ip local, me toco configurar el router de mi casa.

Primero asigne una IP fija al servidor.
Luego abrí el puerto 80 del router y lo mandé a la ip local del servidor.
Este paso depende de cada router.

Luego desde fuera de casa, con la IP publica de mi casa ya puedo acceder a mi servidor.

Comment: No había intentado verlo desde una red fuera de mi casa(¡Funciona!), desde mi casa directamente no abre no se por que, pero bueno ya tengo lo que quería Gracias.

Comment: La solución fácil y rápido para verlo desde casa es modificar el fichero hosts de tu ordenador para que tu ip publica reponda con la ip local de tu servidor. Eso siempre que no lo vayas a cambiar de red :)